# filtering list using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am writing to seek help, in how can I filter data and then merge two results, below:

**Update code***

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private cdw db = new cdw();

    public HttpResponseMessage get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        var data = db.data_qy.AsQueryable();

        if (query.startDate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.tag))
        {
            var ids = query.tag.Split(',');

            data = data.Where(c => c.TAG.Any(t => ids.Contains(t)));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
        {
            var ids = query.name.Split(',');

            data = data.Where(c => c.NAME.Any(t => ids.Contains(t)));
        }

        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);

        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
}
```

entity class:

```
  public partial class data_qy
   {
    public int ID { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TAG { get; set; }

    public string TAG_IS { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UploadDate { get; set; }

}
```

Sample Dataset:

```
 Name               Tag          Tag_IS
 AMCAR 2013-5   03065EAC9   
 ARES 2006-6RA  04009JAA9   
 ARES 2012-1A   04013TAB9   
 ATOM 2003-I A           0182690668
 BACM 2006-2 AM 05950EAG3   
 BCAP 2007-AA3  05530VAN9   
 BCAP 2007-AA3  05530VAN9   
 BCJAF 9 C                   0312888037
 BLNDLN 0                    0213093627
 BLNDLN 0                    0213093627
```

The underlying SQL query should resemble:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[data_qy] 
where TAG like '%78473TAC4%' 
    or TAG LIKE '%05946XYZ0%' 
    OR NAME LIKE '%TAP%' 
    OR NAME LIKE '%STORM%'
```

Using the following list method above, when I run a query such as (`api/test/tag=78473,12669,05946,...` (30 values)), i get a -- Exception Message:

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries

Am I missing something. Any help would be most appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Not sure where the error is coming from, but the `data.Where (c => c.TAG...)` can be shortened considerably by passing in `ids` and using `.Any` directly into the query, instead of looping. That would also negate the need for the call to `.Aggregate`.

Comment: This is probably going to fail in OP's SQL layer; chances are, that's why he went with all this complexity in the first place.

Comment: This is what I'd try: `filteredDara = data.Where(c => ids.Intersect(c.TAGS).Any());` or `filteredDara = data.Where(c => c.TAGS.Any(t => ids.Contains(t));`

Comment: Apology for not making my problem clear, the error is caused on the (!data.ANY) code line.

Comment: Dear @jessehouwing, I tried both of your solutions, but sadly, it keeps throwing -- 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments. error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assuming you use ef 5 or greater you can look at the query by using data.ToString() before the if(!data.Any()). Also which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not in a situation to test this on the spot, but I suspect that either of the following should work:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private cdw db = new cdw();

    public HttpResponseMessage get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        IQueryable<data_qy> data = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.tag))
        {
            var ids = query.tag.Split(',');

            var dataMatchingTags = db.data_qy.Where(c => ids.Any(id =>  c.TAGS.Contains(id)));

            if (data == null)
                 data = dataMatchingTags;
            else
                 data  = data.Union(dataMatchingTags);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
        {
            var ids = query.name.Split(',');

            var dataMatchingName = db.data_qy.Where(c => ids.Any(id =>  c.NAME.Contains(id)));

            if (data == null)
                 data = dataMatchingName;
            else
                 data  = data.Union(dataMatchingName);
        }

        if (data == null) // If no tags or name is being queried, apply filters to the whole set of products
            data = db.data_qy;

        if (query.startDate != null)
        {
            data  = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
        }

        var materializedData = data.ToList();

        if (!materializedData.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);

        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, materializedData);
    }
}
```

I also suspect that you don't need to check against `Null` in your query, since EF will understand that when transforming the Expression Tree to SQL, but if needed, you can add it.

That would remove the need to use the `foreach`, the `Aggregate` and the call to `Count`. and results in a much simpler query that should use the `IN` operator in SQL.

Currently you're executing the same query multiple times (the call to `.Any` at the end will execute the query and then passing the data variable will execute it again. This can be very costly. Instead, materialize the results and act upon that, as above.

Comment: Dear @jessehouwing, Thanks a lot for clarifying this up but I am getting a conversion error, which I am not sure what it means, on the filterData = where (....ANY(...), --- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<API_09.data_qy>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IQueryable<API_09.data_qy>>'.  PLease advice, if possibe. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response back. I have updated my code, in my original post, showing the entire query method I currently calling.  I am also getting another error related to (filterData...line code) -- error ---Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string[]'. Thanks

Comment: Dear @jessehouwing, I would also like to notify, I was originally using the just the (contain) and (split) clause in the query, such as what you have suggested, but the query does not work, when I call multiple (split) parameters such as (api/test?name=storm&tag=7865), it throws a no data response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply back. The query is returning the right values as the query parameters.  Apology for the filterdata variable, it was suppose to commented out. Please advice.  Many thanks.

Comment: You might also want to investigate the new WebAPi support for binding to Query string directly: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/528465, that would allow you to remove the need for the string.split.

Comment: Dear @jessehouwing. Thank you for your response and support. I have small issue with the query above, if I call (api/test?tag=##,##,...), the query works fine.However, if I do not use the line of code -- var data2 = db.data_qy.AsQueryable(); and I call ((api/test?startDate=23/4/2014), the query works and result is shown, otherwise if I do not use that line of code, i get a error -- ExceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null.

Comment: Also, If I use var data2 = db.data_qy.AsQueryable(); and call query((api/test?startDate=23/4/2014&endDate=29/4/2014), the query outputs entire dataset, instead filtering result according to the search query. the (data2) variable is declared after the union method. Thanks for your help and providing a useful link on (split), I shall look into that. Many thanks.

Comment: Dear @ jessehouwing, Thank you very much for your support and updating and resolving the code to latest query issue.  I am very grateful to you help. Thank you!!!!